# How to direct audio out of only 1 side of the ear piece?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Is is possible to code HTML5 with the help of javascript/php to direct audio out of only 1 side of the earpiece? For example playing an audio clip only to the left side of the earpiece.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the StereoPannerNode interface of the HTML5 Web Audio Api:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StereoPannerNode

Just set the panvalue to -1 to direct audio only out of the left side.
Something like this, example mostly taken from posted link.

```
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var myAudio = document.querySelector('audio');

// Create a MediaElementAudioSourceNode
// Feed the HTMLMediaElement into it
var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(myAudio);

// Create a stereo panner
var panNode = audioCtx.createStereoPanner();

panNode.pan.value = -1;

// connect the AudioBufferSourceNode to the gainNode
// and the gainNode to the destination, so we can play the
// music and adjust the panning using the controls
source.connect(panNode);
panNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

Comment: after implementing this it still plays form load speaker in safari on IOS 16